# Delegating constructors and reference parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, pass-by-reference

I would like to implement several constructors for my class via overloading. As I understand the way to do this idiomatically, following the DRY principle, is using a feature called delegating constructors. I also have seen thoughts about using reference parameters everywhere and avoiding pointers at all cost because references is a c++ way etc.

So here is how I see this could be implemented with pointers (which works):

```
class B {};
class C {};

class A {
public:
    A();
    A(const B* b);
    A(const B* b, const C* c);
private:
    const B* b_;
    const C* c_;
};

// These ctors short and concise, delegating work to last ctor
A::A() : A(nullptr, nullptr) {}
A::A(const B* b) : A(b, nullptr) {}

// This ctor contains code that deals with b or c being nullptr
// Ideally I only modify code in this ctor (DRY)
A::A(const B* b, const C* c) : b_(b), c_(c) { 
   //code
}
```

The following, ***obviously***, doesn't work:

```
class B {};
class C {};

class A {
public:
    A();
    A(const B& b);
    A(const B& b, const C& c);
private:
    const B& b_;
    const C& c_;
};

A::A() : A(nullptr, nullptr) {}

A::A(const B& b) : A(b, nullptr) {}

A::A(const B& b, const C& c) : b_(b), c_(c) {
   //code
}
```

So the question is how to implement delegating constructors following semantics in a pointer example but with reference as constructor's parameters.

(Do I totally miss the point here somewhere? Maybe even staring with the overall idea?)

Comment: I assume `b_` and `c_` are references? Please provide a [mre]. You can't assign `nullptr` to a reference, if your value can be null you need to use pointers

Comment: Thanks @AlanBirtles. I have added some code to examples. Hope this further clarifies the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your members of 'A' are references, one way to allow this would be to have some special "null" value for each of your classes:

```
class B {};
class C {};

class A
{
public:
    A();
    A(const B& b);
    A(const B& b, const C& c);
private:
    const B& b_;
    const C& c_;
    static const B null_b;
    static const C null_c;
};

A::A() : A(null_b, null_c) {}

A::A(const B& b) : A(b, null_c) {}

A::A(const B& b, const C& c) : b_(b), c_(c) {
}
```

Comment: The way I see this approach is semantically closest to what I understand about pointer parameterized constructors (first code snippet in question). The question then is it a conventional (common, standard) way to arrange code with delegating constructors and reference parameters ?

Comment: @psb I don't think this has much to do with delegating constructors, its to do with having reference members which may be "null", generally if members can be null then pointers would be more appropriate

Comment: @psb I guess you're focusing too much on the reference rather than what you want to express

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass `nullptr` to a reference. It exists precisely with this purpose.

A pointer is a variable which contains an address to a variable. A reference is the address variable, so it can't refer to nothing and can't be reassigned.

When you write

```
 A(const B& b)
```

you are making a contract. you are stating: *"I want to construct A with a mandatory B object. B being null is not an option here."*

Delegating to this constructor means following its contract. So with this assumption your delegation works fine with:

```
struct B{};

struct A{
  A() : A(B{}){}  // Constructing a pre-defined B object

  A(const B& b) : _b{b}{}
  B _b;  
};


int main ()
{
  A a;
}
```

[Live code here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9572288b79bc819a)

said that, if you want to express a nullable type you can use `std::optional` if C++17 is an option. If you have polymorphic object I'd suggest to use smart pointer to express ownership better and have more control of your code.

Comment: Thanks Moia. Your answer has ideas I have yet to digest. I liked your expression of stating a contract by declaring a parameter as reference or pointer. Your comment on me focusing too much on the reference is definitely relevant.